# Working OpenSceneGraph bindings for Python?

Tags: python, 3d, pygame, collada, openscenegraph

I'm building a rendering engine in Python for fun. I need to load 3D scenes. Any standard modern format like DAE, 3DS, or MAX would work: I can convert my files easily between standard formats.

OpenSceneGraph seems to be the most comprehensive and well-maintained solution. It would be ideal to be able to use it in Python without much hassle. Are there working Python bindings for OSG that are easy to install, work on Mac OS X (I'm on 10.8), and are compatible with the latest versions of OSG?

I searched around and came across osgswig (http://code.google.com/p/osgswig/) and PyOSG (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyosg/), but they don't seem to be actively maintained. I don't see any recent activity related to these packages, and it seems that people had trouble running osgswig on OSX. Ideally, I'd like to find something that "just works", without major compilation hassles. I'd like to just install a package and be able to import a module that will let me load COLLADA or 3DS files.

I also came across pycollada (https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada). It seems active, but fairly early-stage. Ideally, I'd like a reasonably comprehensive package that supports specular maps, normal maps, and other reasonably advanced features. Animation would be nice as well.

In summary, I need to load 3D scenes in Python. Bindings for OSG would probably be ideal, because OSG is so comprehensive. But I need something that works on OSX. I would also prefer something that can be installed reasonably easily. Does something like this exist?

Thanks!

Comment: pycollada is pretty stable now, but animation support isn't complete

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Open Asset Import Library (short name: Assimp). It is a portable Open Source library to import various well-known 3D model formats in a uniform manner. http://www.assimp.org/

Comment: Thanks, I took a look. It doesn't seem to run on Mac OS, though. I'm looking for something that will function on Mac OS.

Comment: For the record, it does run on Mac OS. Which problems did you encounter trying?

Answer (score 1):

You should loot at  panda3D (http://www.panda3d.org/), it's a game engine with extensive python bindings. It has the features you want : http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Features

I used it for a few years and it was a solid tool.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own fork of a mirror of a clone of the osgswig project for a similar purpose. I have it working with OpenSceneGraph version 3.2.1 on Windows and Mac; and it's likely I will eventually polish it for linux too. I'm already delivering one product to customers based on my version of osgswig, and I'm considering making others. Find my fork here:

https://github.com/cmbruns/osgswig

If others show enough interest, I might be coaxed into creating binary installers for my version of the osgswig module, to make installation easier.

If you just want the easiest OpenSceneGraph bindings for OSG 3.2.1, you can stop reading this answer here. Read on for more of my thoughts for the future.

Though I am maintaining a fork of osgswig (as stated above), I sort of hate SWIG, and I would prefer to use bindings based on Boost.Python, rather than on SWIG. For large, complex C++ APIs, like OpenSceneGraph, Boost.Python can be much more elegant than SWIG, both for the API consumer, and for the binding maintainer (me, and me). I found one project using Boost.Python to wrap OSG, at https://code.google.com/p/osgboostpython/, but the developer is lovingly wrapping each part of the interface by hand, and has thus only completed a tiny fraction of the large OpenSceneGraph API.

Taking that Boost.Python based project as inspiration, I created yet another OpenSceneGraph Python binding project, at https://github.com/JaneliaSciComp/osgpyplusplus. Eventually, I want to use this osgpyplusplus project for all my python osg needs. And I would appreciate help in making it ready. Right now, osgpyplusplus suffers from the following weaknesses, compared to osgswig:

1. osgpyplusplus is not yet used in any working product
2. The build environment is tricky to set up, requiring both Boost.Python and Pyplusplus
3. I haven't paid much attention to osgpyplusplus recently, so it might rust away if I continue to ignore it.
4. Though osgpyplusplus probably wraps most of the OpenSceneGraph API, there are probably some important missing pieces that won't be identified until someone tries to develop a significant project with it.
5. It would be a lot of work for me to create a binary module installer for osgpyplusplus at this point, so please don't ask me to.